# How to create a .lib file from a C# DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, dll

I need to create a .lib file from a C# DLL (I think it is C# becuase of this code which calls to the dll https://code.google.com/p/thunder-missile-api/downloads/detail?name=MissileLauncher.cs&can=2&q=) In other word's I need to create a .lib for [DreamCheeky Thunder Missile Launcher](http://www.dreamcheeky.com/thunder-missile-launcher) DLL, which comes with their [software](http://files.dreamcheeky.com.s3.amazonaws.com/software/Thunder.exe) .

Now, what I need to do? I need to operate this device using C++. Easiest way is using their own DLL. The above linked code does it in C#.

I tried importing the DLL file into the project C++, but it seems like some methods are missing, specially methods like `moveMissileLauncher()` which are called in the C# code.

And the best thing is, I might want to move to QT (most probably) so you know, having a .lib is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You want to call managed C# code from your c++ application. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736) is tutorial to make someway to call c# code from your c++ application, i have used this method before, and works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Crating a lib from a managed dll will do no good. You need to use interop 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx

In your specific case, I would write a C++ lib that exposes the methods you need/want to call and forwards them to the managed C# dll using interop

I would do that in C++/CLI, personally. 
A good, more recent article on the options you have is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315414.aspx, or look here on SO for COM/.NET interop and you will find plenty of answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean, a manually write c++ for the dll ?

Comment: @Knight I added a couple of links in my answer. Basically, you will need a proxy/wrapper to forward functions to the managed DLL. So, basically, you will have native exe (C++) -> native DLL (C++/CLI) -> managed DLL

Comment: Based on your needs, you can even collapse the first two steps.. but since you mentioned QT, maybe keeping things separate is better (I don't know how QT may react to C++/CLI). Or you may go through COM interop instead of C++/CLI. The best suggestion I can give you is to read the MSDN articles and weigh your options based on your particular scenario.